# form security issue in razor web pages

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have a hidden form field to delete an item in my razor web pages application

```
<input type="hidden" value="137" name="id">
```

user can easily alter the item value and delete other user's product, how do we secure this ?

Comment: It would help if you posted part of your code where you retrieve form values and update your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do server-side validation to ensure that that user has the appropriate authorization to edit/delete (or any other action) that entity.

As an example, in your `Controller`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
   if (CanUserDeleted(id))
   {
      Delete(id);
      // more magic
   }
   else
   {
      // Give the user an error
   }
}
```

Comment: could you pls provide me an example ?

Comment: i am not using mvc, i am using web pages